# Force Windows 8 to install older version of driver

Tags: windows-8, drivers, display

Recently I installed Windows 8 in my desktop. It's actually 1440*900 monitor. The motherboard manufacturer didn't provided Windows 8 drivers yet. I guess, they wont as it's 2008 model. I have drivers for 7 which gave me correct resolution. But Windows 8 don't comes with 1440*900 driver for my monitor. Is there any way I can suppress the "Best driver installed bla bla" and use the drivers of Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display, Resolution, Graphics drivers mainly based on motherboard drivers. Since I have Intel G33/G31 Motherboard, I can't find the drivers from the official site. But however [DownloadAtoZ.com](http://drivers.downloadatoz.com/vendor_intel_type_video-card/221947,intel-g33-g31-express-chipset-family-display-driver-8-15-10-2697-for-windows-8/) offered me a driver. Though I got this site while Googling, I find it's worth to try since the download link actually points to WindowsUpdate.com.

As I hoped, it worked fine. Based on the update date I guess this driver might be released for CP of Windows 8 and later omitted from RTM. Anyhow I solved my problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't let Windows search for driver. Select that you want to pick the driver from a disk.

[image]

(picture source: eightforums.com)

eightforums.com has a tutorial which explains it step by step:

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9695-driver-install-device-manager-windows-8-a.html

Comment: No. The above tutorial is actually give you option to install driver when there is no installer available. I meant different scenario. I select the driver files. Windows says, it installed the best **after** I choose custom driver.

Comment: click on "Let me pick a list of device drivers" and point to the path.

Comment: It didn't work. Because the available list of drivers comes with Windows installation, which don't have any 1440*900 driver.

Comment: @Jones which Monitor do you use?

Comment: [Samsung SyncMaster 943nwx](http://www.samsung.com/my/consumer/pc-peripherals-printer/monitor/lcd-monitor/LS19MYNKF/XME-spec)

Comment: I still don't see why you fail. Extract the 20071026103718437_SM943NW.exe to a folder like C:\Samsung and use the device manager to point to this folder.

Comment: I got error "The folder .. doesn't contains a compatible software driver for your device....."

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the update driver window from device manager, you choose the "Let me pick" option, and then the "Have Disk" option, you will see the old Install from disk window with the A: drive shown. Browse and choose your driver files from this window and you will be able to Install any driver you want. Even if it don't work afterwards. But it is a way to force a driver install on Windows 8.1.